# Consulta SQL con dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas de configuraciones, una general y una especifica:

tabla *configuraciones*:

```
codigo        contenido
codigo_ga     UA-GENERICO
```

tabla *configuraciones_dominios*:

```
dominio_id        idioma    codigo        contenido
1                 es_ES     codigo_ga     UA-DOM1-ES
2                 (NULL)    codigo_ga     UA-DOM2-GENERICO
2                 es_ES     codigo_ga     UA-DOM2-ES
```

El idioma y el dominio siempre los tengo para pasarlo en la consulta, pero el idioma (en la tabla especifica) es opcional. Ejemplo:

- Para el dominio 1 en español, debería mostrarse "UA-DOM1-ES".
- Para dominio 1 en ingles, debería mostrarse "UA-GENERICO".
- Para dominio 2 en español "UA-DOM-ES".
- y para cualquier idioma del dominio 2 debería mostrarse "UA-DOM2-GENERICO"

¿Es esto posible en una sola consulta y trayendo solo un valor por "código"?

Comment: Me cuesta entender la estructura relacional de tu tabla. Podrías subir tu código SQL donde creaste las tablas, o especificar cual es el `Primary Key` y  `Foreign Key` de tus/entre tablas?

Comment: `configuraciones`(
   `codigo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `contenido` longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`), 
)
`configuraciones_dominios` (
  `dominio_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idioma` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contenido` longtext,
  UNIQUE KEY `configuracion_dominio_idioma` (`dominio_id`,`idioma`,`codigo`)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que tu estructura no me queda del todo clara, el resultado lo puedes lograr con una consulta como esta:

```
select   coalesce(  (select cd.Contenido
                       from configuraciones_dominios cd
                      where cd.codigo = cfg.codigo
                        and cd.dominio_id = Params.dominio_id
                        and cd.idioma = Params.Idioma
                    )
                  , (select cd.Contenido
                       from configuraciones_dominios cd
                      where cd.codigo = cfg.codigo
                        and cd.dominio_id = Params.dominio_id
                        and cd.idioma is null
                    )
                  , cfg.Contenido) Contenido
   from configuraciones cfg
        cross join (select 1 dominio_id, 'es_ES' idioma) Params
 where cfg.codigo = 'codigo_ga';
```

Estoy poniendo los parámetros en la tabla derivada Params, y con eso solo se escriben una vez. Si los vas variando, verás que obtienes el resultado deseado, yo lo he comprobado con este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88651a/20), y me devuelve, para cada parámetro:

```
Sitio  Idioma     Resultado
1      es_ES      UA-DOM1-ES
1      en_US      UA-GENERICO
2      es_ES      UA-DOM2-ES
2      en_US      UA-DOM2-GENERICO
```

Comment: Gracias a este comentario pude darme cuenta de como hacerlo (No conocia COALESCE).
SELECT cfg.codigo, COALESCE(cfg_dom_idi.contenido, cfg_dom.contenido,cfg.contenido) AS config
FROM configuraciones cfg 
LEFT JOIN configuraciones_dominios cfg_dom ON cfg.codigo = cfg_dom.codigo AND cfg_dom.dominio_id = 1 AND cfg_dom.idioma IS NULL
LEFT JOIN configuraciones_dominios cfg_dom_idi ON cfg.codigo = cfg_dom_idi.codigo AND cfg_dom_idi.dominio_id = 1 AND cfg_dom_idi.idioma = 'es_ES'